# 80C188 x86 Processor chip select

Tags: assembly, x86

Good day, I have just been introduced to the 80C188 x86 chip and platform, and I am trying to understand a section of the skeleton code. In my chip connection layout, I have my IO chip connected to PCS1.

However, in the skeleton code given, it is as such

```
; PACS initial, set the parallel port start from 00H
MOV DX, PACS
MOV AX, 0003H ; Peripheral starting address 00H no READY, No Waits
OUT DX, AX
```

They have set the PACS register start address to 0 based on the manual. I am not sure why they have done this as this would mean it is connected to PCS0..

Comment: That code makes no sense.  You can't use PACS as the I/O address because the contents are shifted.

Comment: ok let me make it simple..how do i set the output PCS1 to 0?